# Cypress: add function nameOfPromise as custom command

Tags: cypress

I'm quite new in Cypress and I'm trying to make the things works... Could you please help me a bit? There is a function:

```
function checkInput(selector, nameOfPromise) {
  cy.get(selector).should("contain", nameOfPromise)
}
```

on execution it looks the following way:

```
cy.get("@nameOfPromise").then(nameOfPromise => (checkInput(selector, nameOfPromise)))
```

it works just fine when I add it at the beggining of test but I want to create a custom command from it, so I tried

```
Cypress.Commands.add("checkInput", (selector, nameOfPromise) => {
    cy.get(selector).should("contain", nameOfPromise)
})
```

but it doesn't work. Is there any possible solution? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Calling the custom command instead of the function work very similar to the function

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("checkInput", (selector, nameOfPromise) => {
    cy.get(selector).should("contain", nameOfPromise)
})

it('my test', () => {

  cy.get('something').as('nameOfPromise')
  ...
  cy.get("@nameOfPromise")
    .then(nameOfPromise => {
      cy.checkInput(selector, nameOfPromise)
    })
```

"it doesn't work" could mean 100 things, but if you have things as above it will work.